# How can I improve my question when there is no feedback left by downvoters?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question, asking-questions

Today I posted [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871846/concatenating-a-stack-string-with-a-heap-string-nonsense) about a C++ issue I found a bit confusing. Since I am a complete beginner in C++, all I could do was to write a short summary and ask for advice.

The question attracted a couple of insightful answers and I was quite happy with those. To my complete surprise, an hour later the question had received 3 downvotes without any comment or suggestion.

Since I always put effort into making my posts decently formatted and thorough, it kind of struck a nerve.

I was puzzled as to why. I am not a native English speaker so nuances of language usually elude me. Is it the wording? Tone? Formatting? Too RTFM?

To quote a comment from [visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871846/concatenating-a-stack-string-with-a-heap-string-nonsense/6871924#6871924):

> @Martinho: I missed that OP's passing Buffer the first time. Can't
> imagine someone managing C strings without any idea how the C string
> functions work...

Did the question get downvoted because it displayed ignorance? How could I have asked it differently to avoid the downvotes?

---

**Update**

I just had.. um.. a strange exchange with one of the members from the C++ community. That member posted an answer here attempting to explain the background. However, after realizing <strike>the contradiction in hers/his arguments</strike> a possibility of an extended chat session, the delete link got clicked.

I am not going to reveal the identity but nevertheless will share the discussion. I feel it sheds some light on the issue. Note that the person was apparently not one of the voters.

*The deleted answer*

> I think the accepted answer to the original question also answers this
> question:
>
> *There are lots of problems with your code.*
>
> You asked why one piece of code (with several errors) didn't work,
> when some other code (also with several errors) seemed to work better.
> In reality the difference was just random, and neither of them really
> works.
>
> It took a lot of effort for someone to put together an answer, and I
> didn't have the time (being at work), so would just have downvoted if
> there hadn't been enough downvotes already.
>
> Leaving a comment that there were several errors in the functions
> didn't seem to be constructive either. Guess that those who did
> downvote might have felt the same.

*The comment trail*

> Okay. Are You saying that the C++ community downvoted it because they
> had either no time or no motivation to answer it properly? – *Saul 19
> mins ago*
>
> No, I'm saying it might have been downvoted because it wasn't seen as
> a good question. The lack of comments can be because of limited time.
> It was in my case. – *XXX 15 mins ago*
>
> Note that if you had asked the question right now, I might have
> answered it. Six hours ago I had to do some payed work. – *XXX 8 mins
> ago*
>
> Uh.. why would one want to **downvote a question when busy** but be
> willing to answer it later? To communicate that "your question is
> unwelcome at this time, I am doing paid work, come back later"? In
> such a scenario there is nothing I can do to make it appear
> as a good question. - *Saul 1 mins ago*

Comment: @Cody Gray: All right. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: Much better, I'll remember to +1 this tomorrow when I have more votes. :-)

Comment: he comes here to try and improve and you still downvote him O-o

Comment: Yes, downvotes mean [something different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) on Meta. That's a whole other can of worms...

Comment: "I am a complete beginner in C+" there are those that say that the C++ SO community aren't generally as friendly as the PHP SO community

Comment: c++ developers are angry and cranky from having to do pointer arithmetic all the damned time.  They downvoted you because they wanted you off their lawn, you young whippersnapper.

Comment: C++ was developed to have less competitors. You are a competitor therefore: point--

Comment: I can report from a reliable source that "XXX" deleted his answer to avoid an extended chat session.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Why that question was not seen as a good one is still a mystery to me. Nor do I understand the issue with technical errors. Isn't the whole purpose of SO to have them pointed out for a reward?

Comment: I see you've gotten plenty of upvotes on the original question now since asking this question (+9/-3). That's the opposite of what usually happens when you bring something like this up on Meta. A constructive tone really *does* work.

Comment: @BoPersson: I suspect the real problem was that the "question" seemed to amount to a couple of blocks of code, and asked "what is wrong with my code?". It's nothing new for that to get downvoted. A lot of veteran users are tired of those questions and don't find them particularly interesting. Not to say that I'm agreeing with the downvotes (it was a no-vote question for me personally), but I do understand the sentiment, and I suspect that's what happened here. It's not merely ignorance that caused the downvotes, but it is a collusion of ignorance-related factors. :-)

Comment: @Cody - Like I said in my now deleted answer, I saw the question earlier today while at work. I only gave it a glance, but saw about half a dozen errors, including the subject line, using uninitialized buffers, and drawing the wrong conclusions from that. Had it not already been downvoted, I just **might** have done that. Now I just left it and answered questions from my project lead instead, because that's how I make a living. :-) Now I an only congratulate Saul on his good marketing skill, to get 9 upvotes for his question. I didn't even vote!

Comment: @Bo Persson: Yes.. it's those marketroids again, having technical errors in their questions and drawing wrong conclusions - they should be downvoted when there is no time to address their issues properly. Look Bo, I do understand that You didn't even vote. All I am saying is that zapping a question because of mistaken technical assumptions and not even bothering to comment is a bit rude.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has gotten a lot of support which is quite an accomplishment as a typical question complaining about downvotes doesn't usually get a very warm reception.  I think the reason you succeeded was because you didn't complain but simply asked how you can improve and because it is clear that you did put effort into your question.

Nevertheless, the answer to your humble question is roughly the same as the answer to complaints about downvotes without comments: **don't worry too much about downvotes**.  Of course they sting a little but unless you **only** get downvotes, it just means the community is divided about the question.

One phenomenon that happens is "gut reaction votes" when a question is first posted.  Sometimes a "what am I doing wrong" question will get downvoted with a scolding "too easy, learn to program" attitude or for other flaws.  But then someone posts a really good answer and suddenly the question looks a lot better.  It starts to get mostly upvotes.  The question turned into a [teachable moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teachable_moment).

Your first goal in asking a question is to get answers.  Your second goal is to get a non-negative question score.  Just accept that if you ask an entry-level question in a competitive arena, the risk of a few downvotes is higher.  Do your research before you ask the question and ask the best question that you can.  Then, if you enter the lion's den and still escape unscathed, don't sweat a few downvotes in the process.

Answer (score 4):

> I always put effort into making my posts decently formatted and thorough

It's quite likely that in this case you were just *too thorough*.

- Eg imagine someone posting say 100-lines code example with say 20 errors in it. Thorough, nicely formatted etc. 1st reader spends a minute to check first 5 lines, points to the first error, upvotes - just because it feels good isn't it. 2nd reader spends 2 minutes to check next 10 lines and prior answer, points to second error, upvotes - feels good isn't it. 3rd reader spends half an hour to analyze whole the code and finds out it's actually FUBAR => downwote.

If that's the case, consider focusing your effort on being *concise*. Study [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) principles. Practice. Review other questions and answers and learn what makes them look good / bad to you. Self-review your own questions. Edit when you see a way to *condense*.

Oh and be prepared that it's take a lot more effort than to just be thorough and well-formatted.

Sorry if my answer is lengthy - I didn't have enough time to make it short.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess :
You used 5 tags for your question, but you are missing one important tag : [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) or some similar tag, because your example contains only one c++ keyword `return`. Literally everything in it are windows extensions.

Comment: That.  And it is a C question, enough to raise the ire of C++ users.

Comment: I can not tell if it is a c or c++ question. As I said, I recognized only return.

Comment: `int` is a C++ keyword. And (nitpick) it probably *is* a C++ question, since it uses the keyword `new`, rather than `malloc`. That said, it's a pointer question, specifically about the Windows API `TCHAR` data type. And that requires knowledge of the Windows header files at least as much as it does about pointers.

Answer (score -3):

I've come to the conclusion that voting to close questions is a terrible TERRIBLE way to do things. Several of my questions have ended up getting comments asking for clarification, then edits from me to provide that clarification, and then suddenly they just get deleted - why? Because BEFORE the edits, someone started a vote to delete it. The net result is that I'm finding Stack Overflow to be useful if, and ONLY if, someone else has already asked the question.

Context: [HTML5 Details - can it default to using full width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845761/html5-details-can-it-default-to-using-full-width) - it's been closed because it apparently lacks detail, which it does have. But I have no information and no way to communicate with the person who closed it, because it probably wasn't closed by a person, but by a vote. I'm pretty much ready to close my Stack Overflow account and use the site solely as a guest.

Comment: Your post wasn't deleted, it was closed--answers are blocked until it is sufficiently improved. And you were told why in the closing dialog & got problems & advice in comments. And the site help & meta site tell you more. And you can comment to commenters & in certain cases, like this one, close voters. But you don't need replies to improve your post. Research how the site works & why. Including re comment notifications including use of "@".

Comment: @philipxy Given that I had responded to each of the comments on the post, I don't see how your comment here applies. My apologies on the sloppy terminology; yes, it was closed, not deleted, but the rest is still accurate. And my experience is still as I described: it's been useless asking questions, only worthwhile finding previously-answered questions.

Comment: The question is about down votes without feedback that leaves the OP wondering what could be wrong, not close votes. Your answer here is anecdotal for a different "problem" that for sure has been stated in another question where this answer could fit. For this question this answer doesn't seem relevant or contribute to solving the issue stated by the OP.

Comment: Close votes with all comments having already been addressed? Seems pretty similar to me.