# Why has my specific question been downvoted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, down-votes

I have asked this question:

[Display grand total as the sum of averages (custom subtotal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039883/rdlc-2008-matrix-display-grand-total-as-the-sum-of-averages-custom-subtotal)

Suddenly I find that the question has been downvoted to -1 . What is the reason for this? Can anybody look at the question and tell me how should I rephrase it; I posted sample data and the result which demonstrates the problem .

I know its a tough problem and the answer is not simple but somebody just downvoted it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100278/how-can-i-improve-my-question-when-there-is-no-feedback-left-by-downvoters

Comment: Your question qualifies as "what is wrong with my code?". Also "...it gives undesired results..." well, what are "undesired results"? Is it the wrong number? Wrong formatting? Throws bananas at you? What are "desired results"?

Comment: somebody who has the patience to read the question and who is generous enough to solve the problem will find no fault in the question as you can see from the comments of that post that people are ready to help. I don't mind my meta question being down voted but the original post should had not been as it might be of great help to somebody who is stuck with a similar problem

Comment: fine... deleted

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's a badly asked question. But I do have a few points:

1. **i** when on it's own in English is capitalised as **I**.
2. You posted links to images of data. I know you don't have enough reputation to post images directly yet, but these are only of tables. You could have posted the table as raw text. There are online methods of converting text into a table such as [Senseful Solutions](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).

   There's rarely a need to post an image and we'd much rather all the information needed for the question was contained in the single post, so people don't have to visit other sites in order to answer your question.
3. Most importantly, to quote *"What I want to achieve is mentioned in the image link."*.

   Ummm, no it's not. Your image is chopped on the right hand side. This means that you barely have an indication of what you want to achieve. Do not rely on images to tell others what you need to do. As I wrote above do not rely on images. Actually write out what you want to achieve.

Comment: P.S. I'm not an expert but does your question actually have anything to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: Thank you for editing the question & direct display of images . The second image preview is available at http://www.2imgs.com/28287a5083 . It is mentioned that "(To view the full resolution please click on the image)" . Please do the needful and replace the cropped image in question with the full one. That would be one great help. Thank you

Comment: I've done it for you @Naveen, but I think you've missed the point. I shouldn't have to. When writing a question it should contain everything needed to answer it, right there, in text, on the page. Not in images stored elsewhere, not in images stored with imgur, not in random other links to random other places. _You_ need to actually write to describe what you want. If you need to back this up with supporting evidence from elsewhere then that's fine but your question should make sense if all images and links are removed. Yours does not.